# Why does the background image on one of my cards (out of 12) not display properly?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, grid

For whatever reason my warrior card bg image width is different from the rest. They are all sharing the  same styles via mixin, and all the images are the same size.  I can force a min-width on it and it looks fine, but shouldn't have to do that and I'm wondering why its the only one behaving this way. I've looked up and down the firefox dev tools but can't find an answer. Site demo
Site code:
mixin:

```
@mixin bg-img {
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center 35%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Card:

```
.card {
    border: 1px solid $border-color;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: $card-bg;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;

    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
      display: flex;
    }

    &:hover {
      border: 1px solid $card-heading;
    }

    .bg-image {
      height: 253px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .bg-war {
      background: url("../img/warrior.jpg");
      //   min-width: 244px;
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-pal {
      background: url("../img/paladin.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-hunt {
      background: url("../img/hunter2.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-rog {
      background: url("../img/rogue2.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-prt {
      background: url("../img/priest2.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-dk {
      background: url("../img/dk2.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-sha {
      background: url("../img/shaman.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-mage {
      background: url("../img/mage2.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-lock {
      background: url("../img/warlock.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-monk {
      background: url("../img/monk.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-dru {
      background: url("../img/druid.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }
    .bg-dh {
      background: url("../img/demonhunter.jpg");
      @include bg-img;
    }

    .subtitle {
      font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .font-size-sm {
      font-size: 0.85rem;
    }

    .inner-text {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more text in the warrior than in the hunter - if you make all text 3 chars long, the images will all have different width due to the different number of letters in the title. So you need to wrap the `p`s in a div with fixed (same) width

```
<div class="inner-text">
      <h2>warrior</h2><div style="width:300px">
      <p class="subtitle">tank, damage</p>
      <p class="font-size-sm card-text">
        For as long as war has raged, heroes from every race have aimed to
        master the art of battle. Warriors combine strength, leadership, and
        a vast knowledge of arms and armor to wreak havoc in glorious
        combat.
</p></div>
    </div>
```